# Javascript in googlespreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a counter that counts the cells that include in their content the date before today as a date. However the result in cell 16,1 is always zero as it seems that my loop does not work. I know I can do it with a formula in spreadsheets but I want to use javascript. Also I am trying to find out what is wrong in MY code.
I have wrirtten the following lines of code:

```
function job_counter() {


  var yesterday_jobs=0;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var e = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate())
  var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate())
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  var range_unformated=ss.getRange(2,3,25).getValues()
  var date;
  for (var i=1; i<25; i++){
      date=Date.parse(range_unformated[i])
      Logger.log(date[3])
      if ( date[i] - yesterday.getTime() >= 0 && date[i] != ""  ){
      yesterday_jobs = yesterday_jobs + 1 
    ss.getRange(16,2).setValue(yesterday_jobs)
    }}
    // check yesterday_jobs                       
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem, it uses [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) getting a range of 24x24 cells and iterating it to compare every cell value to see if it is equal to yesterday:

```js
function isYesterday(){
  var yesterday_jobs=0;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row=0;
  var col=0;
  var date;
  var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate())
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);

  range = ss.getRange(1,1,25,25).getValues()
  for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    for ( var j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
      date = Date.parse(range[i][j]);    
      if ( date - yesterday.getTime() <= (24 * 60 * 60 *1000)  ){
        yesterday_jobs = yesterday_jobs + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  ss.getRange(16,2).setValue(yesterday_jobs);
}
```

---

### Things that were wrong...

This is wrong and it is the reason it's not working:

```js
      yesterday_jobs === yesterday_jobs + 1;
```

You should be doing:

```js
      yesterday_jobs = yesterday_jobs + 1
```

**Why?**

Because `==` and `===` are [Comparison operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp), and `=` is an assignment operator.

What you are trying to do is to set a new value to `yesterday_jobs`, not to compare it, so you have to use `=`.

This will solve your problems with the loop assignations.

---

When doing `a = 2` you are  assigning a value to a variable:

`a` value is now equal to `2` value

---

When doing `a == 2` you are asking:

Is `a` equal to `2` in `value`?

---

When doing `a === 2` you are asking

Is `a` equal to `2` in `value` and `type`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I did not know that. However I changed it and still my code does not work. Anythying else that could be wrong?

Comment: Edit and correct your code with this new things you know. 
For example, what I told you before, also, on the if conditions you are asking if row === i. But row does not have any value, because it's never been assigned, it's undefined. You should assign a value to it prior to make any comparison.

Also, you have to format date properly to be able to find it on the spreadsheet:

About date formats: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: Hey @johnjohn1, I've edited the answer, it should solve it. If so, please, select the answer as correct: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have tried the following bases on what you recommened but still does not work. Logger.Log gives me undefined values. I have also edited my original code based on what you recommended.

Comment: I have made it work. However my function does not check the cells values real time for value changes. is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The example below shows how to retrieve and log the items names and items numbers.

```
function logItemstInfo() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
Logger.log('Items name: ' + data[i][0]);
Logger.log('Items number: ' + data[i][1]);
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried logger.log but I can not find the problem. My loop does not seem to work

Comment: @johnjohn, Please tell me your right way, what you want, I do not understand

Comment: Why I get always zero value in the cell 16,1. My code does not seem to work correctly